# Wrong URL syntax?

Tags: html, jsp

After combining some jsp url with bean parameter inside the link href attribute I am getting wrong representation. What can be wrong here?

Here is the code:

```
<form method="post" action="<c:url value="/rest/categories/add/category/to/${categoriesBean.currentCategoryKey}"/>">
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Parent :</td>
        <td id="parentKey"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Name :</td>
        <td><input id="categoryName" type="text"/></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Attached is the presentation:

[image: Attached is the presentation]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it like this...not aware of `jsp` but it's the only quotes issue on line 1

```
<form method="post" action='<c:url value="/rest/categories/add/category/to/${categoriesBean.currentCategoryKey}"/>'‌​>
```

Comment: @ArsenAlexanyan did you tried removing the latter thing `">`?

Comment: else try this `action='<c:url value="/rest/categories/add/category/to/${categoriesBean.currentCategoryKey}"/>'>`

Comment: Of course. The problem just became visible after bean property I have added bean property, without that it works perfect.

Comment: Am not aware of the jsp part, the only issue I see here is of quotes